# CSS wrapping differences between text and numbers

Tags: html, css

The below HTML and CSS (live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/zUk63/1/) renders the following:

[image]

As seen, text in the `<dd>` elements will wrap and show each line, however, numbers (actual IP addresses) will not wrap but will truncate and not display the second line.  I get similar results with current versions of IE, FF, and Chrome.

What causes this and how do I make the numbers also wrap and display?

HTML

```
<div class="record-details">
    <dl class="info">
        <dt>Row 1 title with some text:</dt>
        <dd>Some text goes here. Bla bla bla. Bla bla bla</dd>
        <dt>Row 2 title with some numbers:</dt>
        <dd>55.444.33.222,192.168.0.100,192.168.0.102</dd>
        <dt>Row 3 title with some numbers and text:</dt>
        <dd>55.444.33.222,192.168.0.100,192.168.0.102, bla bla bla</dd>
        <dt>Row 4 title with some text and numbers:</dt>
        <dd>bla bla bla,bla bla bla, 55.444.33.222,192.168.0.100,192.168.0.102</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.record-details {
    width: 300px;
}
.record-details .info dt, .record-details .info dd {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.record-details .info dt {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting spaces in between your commas? Specifically in Rows 2,3, and 4?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast  Yes, now that you brought it up.  Please explain why a space causes the line to wrap.  Seems like long alpha text will also need the space.

Comment: Did breaking the words up work?

Comment: IP addresses are not supposed to wrap. You should describe the real problem that made you try to squeeze IP addresses into some limited width where they cannot possibly fit.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  Your response had nothing to do with my question and is irreverent.  That being said, my question was bad and deserved your downmark but for other reasons as it had nothing to do with numbers but with applying `word-wrap` or even `word-break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using `word-wrap`:

```
.record-details {
    width: 300px;
}
.record-details .info dt, .record-details .info dd {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.record-details .info dt {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use word-break and white-space properties of css for dd element.

```
.record-details .info dt, .record-details .info dd {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: pre-line;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

There is also word-wrap property of css which you might wanna look at.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zUk63/2/

Answer (score 1):

add `word-wrap:break-word` attribute to

```
.record-details .info dt, .record-details .info dd{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```